# Build Word Document from template

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I have a request to create a word document on the fly based on a template provided to me. I have done some research and everything seems to point at OpenXML. I have looked into that, but the cs file that gets created is over 15k lines and is breaking my VS 2010 (causing it to not respond every time I make a change).

I have been looking at this tutorial series on Open XML
http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2011/10/13/getting-started-with-open-xml-development.aspx

I have done things in the past with text files and Regular Expressions, but since Word encrypts everything, that does not work. Are there any other options that are fairly lightweight for creating word documents from templates.

Answer (score 3):

//Hi, It is quite simple.

```
            //First, you should copy your Template file into another location.
            string SourcePath = "C:\\MyTemplate.dotx";
            string DestPath = "C:\\MyDocument.docx";
            System.IO.File.Copy(SourcePath, DestPath);

            //After copying the file, you can open a WordprocessingDocument using your Destination Path.

            WordprocessingDocument Mydoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(DestPath, true);

            //After openning your document, you can change type of your document after adding additional parts into your document.
            mydoc.ChangeDocumentType(WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);

            //If you wish, you can edit your document 
            AttachedTemplate attachedTemplate1 = new AttachedTemplate() { Id = "MyRelationID" };

            MainDocumentPart mainPart = mydoc.MainDocumentPart;
            MySettingsPart = mainPart.DocumentSettingsPart;

            MySettingsPart.Settings.Append(attachedTemplate1);

            MySettingsPart.AddExternalRelationship("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/attachedTemplate", new Uri(CopyPath, UriKind.Absolute), "MyRelationID");



            //Finally you can save your document.
            mainPart.Document.Save();
```

Answer (score 2):

I am currently working on something along these lines and I have been making use of the [Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) and the [OpenXmlPowerTools](http://powertools.codeplex.com/) The approach been taken is taking the actual template file opening it up and putting text into various place holders within the template document. I have been using content controls as the place markers.

The SDK tool to open up a document has been invaluable in being able to compare documents and see how it is constructed. However the code generated from the tool I have been refactoring heavily and removing sections that are not being used at all.

I can't talk about doc files but with docx files they are not encrypted they are just zip files that contain xml files

[Eric White's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/) has a large number of examples and code samples which have been very useful

Comment: What parts did you have to take out? The amount of code this tool creates is insane.

Comment: So the main part of what I am doing is a template file will be uploaded to the system and saved as a byte array. The template file has content controls which are I use as place markers. When I process it I take the template byte array, open it using the OpenXML SDK and then find all of the content controls and populate them based on the Id and then the value saved in the database. I leverage the template heavily and use the SDK mainly to replace text. The SDK Tool I mainly use to look at how to build it in code and then I write it cleaner in the code.